# Is Scipy's sign() not guaranteed working?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix of a graph `A`. After `A = A.sign()` there are still some elements that are not 1 or 0 or -1.

```
In [35]: A = A.sign()

In [36]: A.getcol(0).data
Out[36]: 
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,    
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.])

In [37]: A
Out[37]: 
<519403x519403 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3819116 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

On the other hand `numpy.sign()` works fine.

```
In [50]: a = A.getcol(0)

In [51]: np.sum(a.todense())
Out[51]: 58.0

In [52]: np.sum(np.sign(a.todense()))
Out[52]: 57.0
```

Comment: What was the original value?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Original value is too long, that's why I use sparse matrix, but `A.getcol(0).data` is the same as after `A.sign()`

Comment: Can you find out which value(s) in your original `A` matrix gave a `sign` of 2 (e.g.  `A.data[A.sign().data == 2]`)?

Comment: @ali_m It's extremely strange, it shows none of the element is 2! But I always get 2 with A.getcol(0).data

Comment: It's going to be very hard to answer your question unless you can give us a reproducible example. Can you observe the same behavior using a smaller slice of the rows/cols in your full matrix?

Comment: @ali_m See my answer to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I got the answer. It's all about the internal data structure `Scipy` uses.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

xs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 2])
ys = np.array([2, 3, 1, 1, 1])
A = coo_matrix((np.ones((5,)), (xs, ys)))
```

At this point `A` is a `<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type numpy.float64'>' with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>`, although we have two elements in the same coordinate `(3, 1)`. And `A = A.sign()` only performs on the 5 elements, which are all 1 in the first place.

```
>>> A.data
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

>>> A.todense()
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.]])

>>> A = A.sign()
>>> A.todense()
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  2.,  0.,  0.]])
```